# Solve $3\log_{10}(x-15) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, exponential-function

$$3\log_{10}(x-15) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^x$$

I am completely lost on how to proceed. Could someone explain how to find any *real* solution to the above equation?

Comment: Is the log a natural log?  Or base 10?

Comment: @ncmathsadist Sorry, I should have specified. Its base 10.

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions or complex solutions?

Comment: @S.B. I am looking for all real solutions.

Comment: @abc: It can have at most one  real solution, because the LHS is strictly increasing while the RHS is strictly decreasing (actually, it has exactly one solution). Obviously you must look at $x>15$. I'm not sure if you can find a solution explicitly, but you can solve it numerically.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%283*log_10%28x-15%29%3D2%5E%28-2x%29%2Cx%29

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider left and right sides at  $x=16$ and $x=17$.  You won't find an explicit "closed-form" solution, but you can prove that it exists.

Comment: Thanks Robert. The solution is approximately 16 (which I found through just substituting the values in). Sorry, but my mathematical skills are relatively elementary - what is a "closed form solution"? The Wikipedia article on it was very rigorous and hard to understand.

Comment: @abc: "closed form" solution means a formula using only elementary operations (addition, substraction, multiplication, division) plus a handful of functions (exponentiation, roots and logarithms, trigonometric).

Comment: "Closed-form" is a rather subjective term: basically you allow "well-known" functions, but people will differ on precisely which ones to include.

Answer (score 2):

Put 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)  = 3\log_{10}(x - 15) - \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^x.
\end{equation*}
We have $f$ is a increasing function on $(15, +\infty)$.
Another way,
$f(16)>0 $ and $f(17)>0$. Therefore the given equation has only solution belongs to $(16,17)$.

Comment: Thanks. What you did above seems to be just an approximation - isn't there a formal way to find an exact solution?

Comment: Exact solution is too difficult to find.

Comment: At  x=16 we have $log_{10}(16-15)=0$ so $f(16)<0$. I guess that's what you should have written in your answer anyway, since the statement  $f(17)>0$ is right. You want a sign change to guarantee a zero in between.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=16+y$. After approximating $\log(1+y)$ with $y - \frac{y^2}{2}$, $(\frac{1}{4})^y = \exp(-\log(4) y)$ with $1 - \log(4) y$, $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ with $1 - \epsilon$, get 
$$y \approx \frac{\log(10)}{3 \cdot 4^{16}}.$$

WIMS Function Calculator gives the exact solution, $1.7870412306 \cdot 10^{-10}$ compared to the approximation, $1.7870412309 \cdot 10^{-10}$.

Comment: Please check if my LaTeX-editing did not mess up your equations. In any case, (+1) for the nice approach.